# arm assembly if(expression && expression)

Tags: assembly, arm

What would be the most elegant way to do this in ARM assembly?

```
If(x0 == x1 && y0 == y1)
  {
    ...
  }
```

Assuming all values are already in registers

```
equal:
  cmp r2, r3
  beq are_equal
  b not_equal
check: 
  cmp r0, r1
  beq equal
not_equal:
```

Comment: For which ARM architecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am thinking something like this, but I have to stare at it some more...

```
cmp r2,r3
cmpeq r0,r1
bne skip
...
skip:
```

Comment: Section 9.2.3 of the ARMv5 ARM ARM has a similar sequence, entitled *Conditional compare instructions*.  The only difference is that `bne skip` can be encoded as a bunch of conditional `xxxeq` instructions.

Comment: sure all arm instructions can be conditionally executed (full sized not thumb).  I dont know what the OP's ... includes so just put a branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably GCC generate some elegant code for you by doing this:

```
register int x0 asm ("r2");
register int x1 asm ("r3");
register int y0 asm ("r0");
register int y1 asm ("r1");
if(x0 == x1 && y0 == y1)
{
    ...
}
```

Compile this, then look at the disassembly.